# Difference between parallel hint and full parallel oracle hints

Tags: sql, performance, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please explain what is the Difference between parallel hint and full parallel oracle hints

example :

Difference between these two queries

`select */*+ FULL(table1) PARALLEL(table1, DEFAULT) */ from table1` and

```
select */*+PARALLEL(table1, DEFAULT) */ from table1
```

My questions are

1)What is the difference ? 
2) which one is better and why?

Comment: have you tried and found any difference ?

Comment: `*/*+PARALLEL(table1, DEFAULT) */` You missed a space after `+`, so it is not a hint anymore.

Comment: ok thanks but the main idea is to know the difference . I have used FULL and parallel together but the person reviewing asking why am i using FULL rather than using simply PARALLEL

Answer (score 1):

FULL will force a full table scan on the table specified and ignore indexes. In your example this makes no difference as you have no where clause so there's going to be a full table scan anyway.

PARALLEL in your statement is object based (table1) and it will have been built with a default, so your statement is likely changing nothing because you have specified "DEFAULT" anyway.

I highly doubt you will see any difference between those 2 queries you posted.

Comment: This is a sample query but there are WHERE clause in the original one . So using parallel alone will result in different result set ?